# Query for existence in HQL efficiently

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a class `Employee` with three class members: **id, isVisible, sectionId**.

I want to query in HQL:

1. If a certain section has any Employees at all
2. If so - are all the employees within that section hidden.

Now I am doing something like:

```
SELECT count(e.id), count(nullif(e.isVisible,0)) 
        from Employee e where sectionId = :sectionId
```

But counting is not so efficient because **it requires a full table scan**, and I don't need the number counted.

I can do two queries instead.

Query the section for employees by running a simple select and limiting the number of results to a single result:

```
SELECT e.id from Employee e where sectionId = :sectionId
```

And if a result is returned, query for the first employee in the section that is visible:

```
SELECT e.id from Employee e where visible = 1 and sectionId = :sectionId
```

My question is: Can I do both checks in a single query?

Comment: How will you distinguish results if condition will be:

1. true, false 
2. false, false

Does FALSE for both meet your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in getting one row from each query you can full outer join them to get a single row back with two columns. You will need to alias Employee to E1 and E2.